# magento 2 - enable form key validation on contact us page

Tags: magento2

Form key validation is not there on the M2 contact page. While posting the information from outside of the project also sending the email to the Admin.

Ex: We posted the contact us page information from ARC to our m2 URL(Your project/contact/index/post/). It is submitting the form and sending the email to the Admin.

Answer (score 1):

Untested code, but it looks like the way to go: 
Copy the `contact_index_index.xml` layout file from the contact module to your theme  in `Magento_Contact/layout/contact_index_index.xml` and make it look like this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Contact Us</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\FormKey" name="contact_form_key" as="contact_form_key" /><!-- this is added -->
                <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

then, do the same with the template `app/code/Magento/Contact/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml` and add this inside the `form` tag:  `<?= $block->getChildHtml('contact_form_key') ?>`

Then you can write an `around` plugin for the `Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post` class.

```
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Plugin\Contact;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
class PostPlugin 
{
    private $validator;
    private $request;
    private $resultRedirectFactory;
    private $messageManager;
    public function __construct (
         Validator $validator, 
         \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
         \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager;
         \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $redirectFactory;
    ) {
        $this->validator = $validator;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->redirectFactory = $redirectFactory;
    }
    public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post $subject, callable $proceed) 
    {
        if ($this->validator->validate($this->request)) {
            return $proceed();
        }
        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Invalid form key.'));
        $redirect = $this->redirectFactory->create();
        $redirect->setPath('contact/index/index');
        return $redirect;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add the form key validation to the contact us page.
Given code will help you for fix the issue.

Please test it before adding the code.

> **theme/Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtml**

```
?php 
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); //instance of\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager
$FormKey = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey'); 
?> 
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<form class="form contact"
      action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getFormAction()) ?>"
      id="contact-form"
      method="post"
      data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>"
      data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>

      <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $FormKey->getFormKey();?>">
```

> **app/code/Dcw/Vendor/etc/di.xml**

```
<preference for="Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post" type="Dcw\Vendor\Controller\Contact\Index\Post" />
```

> **app/code/Dcw/Vendor/Controller/Contact/Index/Post.php**

```
    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost() || !$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                __('Invalid form key.')
            );
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
    }
```

Comment: this works, but using object manager is discouraged, specially in templates.